# Is it possible to switch the scope of a bean during runtime?

Tags: jsf-2, controller, javabeans

I am using JSF 2.0 to build an app.
What i wish to do is depending on whether a checkbox is ticked or not by the user, i wish to change the scope of the bean from request to session .. is this possible ?

Or override the default 'session' scope with request scope when the checkbox is ticked ...

I tried researching a lot , but i am not even sure if this is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to change the scope of a managed bean during runtime. You can however easily change the behavior of a bean during runtime.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MultiScopedBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{requestScopedBean}")
    private RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean;

    @ManagedProperty("#{sessionScopedBean}")
    private SessionScopedBean sessionScopedBean;

    private boolean sessionScoped; // Bind this to the checkbox.

    // ...

    public Object getSomeProperty() {
        if (sessionScoped) {
            return sessionScopedBean.getSomeProperty();
        } else {
            return requestScopedBean.getSomeProperty();
        }
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(Object someProperty) {
        if (sessionScoped) {
            sessionScopedBean.setSomeProperty(someProperty);
        } else {
            requestScopedBean.setSomeProperty(someProperty);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Yes, it'll end up in quite some boilerplate, but that's what you get for such an odd requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help Balus! I ended up having a separate model object per page when the boolean was unchecked . so the states are saved and rendered separately . The controller has a method getModel that decides which model object to return depending on what page called it and if the boolean was unchecked. (which equals to Have request scope)

If the boolean was checked , then the same model is returned , and hence the state is saved and the same data can be seen over multiple pages

However, I have yet to try your solution ! Thanks for the help !